# EF Core ToArray analog

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Most of you know that ToList(), ToArray() use a lot of memory because they recreate the array after N element. I need to get all rows from table and I wrote smth like this

```
ToArray(_dbContext.MyTable.Count(), _dbContext.MyTable.Select(x => ...})

T[] ToArray<T>(int arraySize, IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
      var result = new T[arraySize];
      byte tempIndex = 0;
      foreach (var item in list)
      {
        result[tempIndex] = item;
        tempIndex++;
      }
      return result;
    }
```

This code uses about 10% less memory than simple

```
_dbContext.MyTable.Select(x => ...}).ToList() \ ToArray()
```

Does EF have something similar to my code?

Comment: Your code is *not* efficient. It's actually worse. It executes *two* queries, one to retrieve the count and another one to retrieve the data. The way it's written, putting all calls in the same expression, prevents the use of async execution that could reduce blocking. The *efficient* way would be to create a `List<T>` with a specific capacity and add the incoming rows to it. Simply specifying a good-enough capacity will reduce memory usage enormously

Comment: If you really want to optimize your code, settle for IEnumerable or IQueryable instead of calling **any** ToArray() or ToList() method. You can use the base IEnumerable for databinding or looping through to create the data for a view, and you'll save a ton of extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not have this, but neither is the proposed method a good solution.

The proposed solution is not good because it runs two queries on the database, and that extra database call will tend to outweigh the extra RAM use. But let's say you know the size of the results (maybe because of pagination) and can skip the extra database query. *Even then, this is **still slower** than it needs to be*.

Instead, the way to optimize this is by recognizing that neither `ToArray()` or `ToList()` are necessary in the first place in most situations. Learn to work with the resulting `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable`, `IAsyncEnumerable`, etc directly. You can already use them for databinding or in a `foreach` loop to create whatever result you need; there's rarely a real need to call `ToArray()` at all.

Most of the time when you *seem* to need `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, it's because you're calling a method asking for an argument of that type. These methods should also be updated to instead ask for `IEnumerable` or `IAsyncEnumerable`. If you can push this all the way down the chain, the memory efficiency of your code can be increased **dramatically**, because the full result set is **never** loaded into memory; you only ever have one record in memory at a time.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, what about to get all data from db with EF core asynchronously without calling ToListAsync() ?

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable`

Answer (score 2):

You are using less memory, but for sure, this operation will take more time running if the table is big and/or your database is non local.

You are performing two queries in the database, something like:

1. ```
   select count(*) from MyTable
   ```
2. ```
   select * from MyTable
   ```

EF uses a single query to achieve the same functionality. I think 10% memory is a very small price to pay for the better performance. Because of that, EF does not have this behavior.

Comment: Yes, agree with you. Some tables have already known number of records and it won't change, so instead of _dbContext.MyTable.Count() I can put already known number.

Comment: I`ve heard that the EF Core 6 (from .net 6) has a lot of optimizations. Please see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-aspnet-core-6/#entity-framework-core

Comment: Using a List with a good-enough capacity would reduce memory usage too